# Type erasure with templated method

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, type-erasure

I have a number of classes which take an object of unspecified type and return a result with a fixed type. Additionally these objects are templated which changes the computation of the results. I would like to hide these objects behind a common interface. The example below should make it clear. `struct Work` is the interface and there exist multiple classes like `struct WorkImpl`. Additionally there are multiple types like `struct A` and `struct B` which interact. In my case they are templated as well and must not be polymorphic. The problem is how to "forward" the work call to the WorkImpl object?

```
#include <iostream>

struct Result
{

};

struct Work
{
  virtual ~Work() { }

  template <typename U>
//  virtual Result work(const U& u) = 0;  // this is not possible, of course!
  Result work(const U& u) { std::cout << "Work" << std::endl; }
};

struct B
{

};

struct A
{
  A& operator =(const B& b) { return *this; }
  Result result() { return Result(); }
};

template <typename T>
struct WorkImpl : public Work
{
  template <typename U>
  Result work(const U& u)
  {
    std::cout << "WorkImpl" << std::endl;
    T t;
    t = u;
    return t.result();
  }
};

int main()
{
  Work* w = new WorkImpl<A>();
  w->work(B());
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you do with the variable of type `U` within `work` in the various implementations?  Anything in common between the various impls?  Do you have a fixed set of `A` `B` types?  Full double-dispatch type erasure, where you erase based off of two independent types not defined at the point of erasure, isn't (as far as I know) doable in C++ (that basically requires run-time compilation in a world of dlls).  The tricks used for double-dispatch of virtual functions can sometimes be adapted to be used at compile time, but more details are required.

Comment: Sorry, "point of erasure" is a bit vague (the "point of erasure" is arguably where the erasure code is invoked with a fixed type).  "code of erasure" might be better?  (the code that does the type erasure).  I need to go and learn more mathematical theory behind type erasure (I'd guess some subset of type theory?) so I can speak the words that mean the things.

Comment: Agree with @Yakk. The thing you want to achieve cannot be solved without further constraint - if it were possible they would have allowed virtual templated methods. If the set of possible types `A` or `B` is small you can solve your problem with overloads instead of template function (which can be virtual)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see what the question is.

The code compiles.

You don't want to polymorphism but

- you forget that static polymorphism is also polymorphism
- you gratuitously use inheritance, despite the fact that there is no common interface at all

I'd suggest to just get the parameter out of the interface. The simplest way to type-erase that would be to use `std::function<Result()>` and be done.

I can add a small sample if required.

Comment: Isn't this more of a comment?  "I don't see what the question is" makes it hard to be an answer to a question!

Comment: I have to agree that this appears more like a comment than an answer to me.

Comment: @Yakk No. He's asking on how to type erasure on what he wants to do. `std::function<Result()>` answers that. The rest is just helpful notes, yes

Comment: @sehe `std::function<Result()>` type erases invoking with nothing.  He wants to invoke with a templated type, not with nothing.  I guess `std::function<Result()>` is **an** answer to the question about "how do I type erase a templated signature", merely a wrong answer?  ;)  I guess this could be a "XY problem" answer, but until the OP clarifies, you don't have access to the underlying problem, no?

Comment: @Yakk I'm very very interested in how you'd erase the only difference (the argument type) then without... erm.... erasing that. Of course you can (as you seem to be hinting in the comments) aim for variant visitation, but that is realistically just as expensive.